# Insert array value into table column

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to write a function that will insert data into a MySQL table like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
    if ($header[$i] == $user_table_property->name) {
        $import = "
INSERT into testing (
    $header[$i]
) values (
    '$data[$i]'
)";
    }
}
```

If I have something like this, it will just insert first data into first column, can I know what should I change or add? I Googled some examples and edited it myself, but it's still not working.

Here is the longer part of the codes.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "<br></h1>";
    echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $headers;
}


$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    $header = fgetcsv($handle);


    while(! feof($handle)){


while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                $num = count($data);

               mysql_select_db("EMC", $db);

               $sql = "SELECT * from CSVtest";
               $result = mysql_query($sql,$db);

                   while ($user_table_property = mysql_fetch_field($result)) 
                            {

                  for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){

                                  if($header[$i] == $user_table_property->name )
                                               {

                                               $import = "insert into CSVtest ( `" . $header[$i] . "`) values ('" . $data[$i] . "')";

                                               }

                                           }

                              mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error()) ; 
                            }

                                                       } 
               }

fclose($handle);

print "Import done";
```

Comment: Are you trying to pick off the first value in the list as the header to insert into the table? As in, `userid`,`aaa`,`aku`,`pwk`, etc., with each representing a new row with one column?

Comment: Also, your code formatting is very distracting.

Comment: @Jared Farrish User will need to put a header such as "FirstName,LastName,Cell..." at the first row,and I will take the values as the column names to be inserted.Even if there are other column names which is not exist in table, it will just ignore it.Yes I know...so sorry about it...

Comment: Have you thought about [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) in MySQL?

Comment: What I would imagine you'd need to do (if `LOAD DATA INFILE` won't work for some reason) is turn CSV file row data into a `$columns` and `$values` arrays as you read in the file, checking and adding to each array a confirmed header and it's row contents as necessary. Then using those two arrays, create `INSERT` statements per row by iterating over `$values`, then do the `mysql_query($import)`. You have to turn your current table-layout CSV format into arrays that can be iterated over without losing the referential integrity of each row and column, though.

Comment: Sorry, I've got to go. I'll check on this later.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Sorry for my late response , I got to go as well...I will back later.Really thanks for willing to spend time on this..I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Ok thanks for your hints.So should I use mysql_fetch_field to check if the column is correct and needed?

Comment: Yes, you should validate the columns and only attempt to insert columns that you have in the table. I would really look into the `LOAD DATA INFILE` functionality; this is much simpler than making a script. The only drawback I can see is if you have conditions in which CSV files may be uploaded for table insertion that have columns that don't exist in the DB and you *can't* **not** let them upload the file. Otherwise, you could just read the first line (to get headers), validate the headers, and on validation, `LOAD DATA INFILE`, otherwise, "Error: Columns are not correct [etc]...".

Comment: @Jared Farrish Thank you.But I not really know how to use LOAD DATA INFILE...

Comment: Well, I would counter and say you don't really know how to manually do what `LOAD DATA INFILE` does naturally. Read the documentation for it that I linked in the third comment above. There are less steps involved in using it than reading the file and manually creating `INSERT`s, especially the way you're demonstrating here, which is equivalent to an `INSERT` per cell (instead of per row, as I described in my first long comment).

Comment: @Jared Farrish Thank you so much Jared , I will and now searching for more examples of LOAD DATA INFILE to learn and understand it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I tried something like this:           mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE "csv.csv" INTO TABLE CSVtest FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");     
      But I get access denied error...

Comment: You need to move the file to another location that your MySQL instance can access; the server upload temp directory (or wherever `csv.csv` is located) it must not have access to.

Comment: You also probably want to get it an absolute path, instead of a relative one.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Thank you I will try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you that you're not interpolating the array values properly:

```
$import = "
INSERT into testing (
    {$header[$i]}
) values (
    '{$data[$i]}'
)";
```

When they're array values, you have to use `{}` around the variable and index (or indices) for it to expand the variable value.

Also, it should probably be doing something like this:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($data[$i]);
$import = "
INSERT into testing (
    `{$header[$i]}`
) values (
    '$value'
)";
```

You don't have any `mysql_query()` or whatnot in the `if` statement, so it's not apparent the code is going to work (you can't run `$import` after the `for` loop or it will only have the last `$import` set).

The whole technique you're using here doesn't seem correct anyway; you probably actually want to build the column and value lists, then after the `for` loop, `implode()` them into a string for `$import`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'm actually doing something related to csv import..and this is part of the codes,but I'm not sure which part is wrong...

Comment: Right, I see now your note about only the first value. What does this: `$user_table_property->name` represent? It appears this doesn't change. I would suggest putting more of the code in question into your answer.

Comment: I will put more of the code,will be greatly appreciated if you willing to take a look. It's about when a user import a csv,it will just pick the column needed and store into database,someone suggest me to get the table column list before build the query,so I try something like this...

Answer (score 4):

let's say you have,

```
$headers = array(..);
$data = array();
```

try this

```
$sql = "insert into table_name(".implode(",",$headers).") values(".implode(",",$data).")";
```

Surely data should be escaped and order of headers should match order of data.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Two issues: One, the `if` check is not demonstrated, and the `values` list needs `'` around the values (most likely, or at least it can't be assumed otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"INSERT INTO `testing` ( `$header[$i]` ) 
           VALUES
            ('$data[$i]');"
```

Also, it's not very recommended to write it this way. You better write it like:

```
"INSERT INTO testing( `" . $header[$i] . "` ) 
           VALUES
            ('" . $data[$i] . "');"
```